# Remove case sensitive feature from Search2

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using **Select2** for the select boxes and Select2 is not searching data which is case sensitive. For example I have **LHE** in the list but when I search **lhe** it displays nothing any help will be appreciated here is the code I am using. Trust me I have read many solutions and tried those as well but none are working. here is the code.

```
<script>
function matchCustom(params, data) {
// If there are no search terms, return all of the data
if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
  return false;
}

// Do not display the item if there is no 'text' property
if (typeof data.text === 'undefined') {
  return null;
}

// `params.term` should be the term that is used for searching
// `data.text` is the text that is displayed for the data object
if (data.text.indexOf(params.term) > -1) {
  var modifiedData = $.extend({}, data, true);
  modifiedData.text;

  // You can return modified objects from here
  // This includes matching the `children` how you want in nested data sets
  return modifiedData;
}

// Return `null` if the term should not be displayed
return null;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".destination").select2({
        matcher: matchCustom,
    });
    $(".departure").select2({
        matcher: matchCustom,
    });
});
```

Comment: What happens when you simply convert your `params.term` to lowercase before your search?

Comment: Sir I have changed Select2 and made a custom solution to it and it is working perfectly fine for me.